# Asp.net mvc send parameter to action with submit button in the partialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, submit

My partialView is Opened in the modal dialog form, User select special row, I want to Submit the parent form with special value as a parameter.

My parent form is:

```
<form id="mainForm" action="<%= Request.RawUrl %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and my submit button in the modal dialog (and in the GridView) that post data to action is:

```
<button name="selectVehicle" id="<%= item.id %>" value="selection" type="button" onclick="$('#mainForm').submit()">
                    OK
                </button>
```

this is work correctly and all my data Post to the Action, but how can i send special Value to the action using this submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field, and update the value in the onclick handler.